# Parentheses inside command substitution expression

Tags: bash, syntax-error, parentheses, command-substitution

I need to get array of filenames that have .jpg or .png extensions in my bash script. For that purpose I write this command:

```
imagesArray=( $(ls (*.png|*.jpg)) )
```

which supposed to execute `ls` command with `(*.png|*.jpg)` argument that defines set of files to output for `ls` command and then wrap command substitution of `ls` command in extra parentheses to make array of `ls` output.

Unfortunately, I get an error:
`` command substitution: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `(' ``
The problem lies in parentheses of `(*.png|*.jpg)` expression that are inside the parentheses of command substitution, as far as I know.

Help me with that issue please

Comment: `(*.png|*.jpg)` is not a valid glob pattern in bash. Therefore, the `|` is taken as a pipe operator, which causes the error message you  are seeing. See the section titled _Pathname Expansion_ in the bash man page for a definition of the allowed pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `ls`, and shouldn't. See [Why not parse ls?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Just put the wildcards directly in the array:

```
set -o nullglob
imagesArray=(*.png *.jpg)
```

Setting the `nullglob` option means the wildcards will expand to empty values if there's no match, rather than expanding to the wildcard itself.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Could you clarify what is the name of the expression  like that please? Is that kind of command substitution too? I mean `(*.png *.jpg)` expression.

Comment: It's just an ordinary wildcard, just like in `ls *.png` The parentheses make an array, just like in your question.

Comment: ok. but what would I have to do if I still needed to use parentheses inside command substitution?

Comment: You use them the same way you use them outside command substitution. The problem you had is that `(*.jpg|*.png)` is not valid syntax anywhere. I suspect you meant `*.*(jpg|png)`  (which requires enabling extended globbing) or `*.{jpg,png}`

Comment: But why than `ls (*.jpg|*.png)` works if it is executed in command line not in bash script file?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I get `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: I suspect you're using `zsh` as your interactive shell, not `bash`. What does `echo $0` show?

Comment: sure, i'm using zsh as an interactive shell

Comment: why does zsh behave in that way?

Comment: Because the zsh designers decided this would be more useful. It has lots of its own extensions, just as bash does.